# Creating Netezza external table using zipped text file

Tags: netezza

I am new to IBM Netezza SQL.
Is it possible to create Netezza external table using zipped text file?

File is very large, I am trying to create external table directly from zipped text file if that is possible in Netezza.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Currently it is not possible to use a compressed file for external table.
Documentation link -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=command-sql-grammar-create-external-table